# setRequestHeader not adding request header to wcf call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I am trying to make a call to wcf function using ajax as below:

```
$.ajax({
        url:http://localhost:64121/Test.svc/json/GetNumber?X='+ var1 + '&callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BasicAuthTest");
        },
        success: function(trackingData) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

WCF code is beaking and is receving the request

```
public class CustomUserNameValidatorBasic : ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {
        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var msg = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

                // If user requests standart help-page then ignore authentication check.
                if (msg.Properties.ContainsKey("HttpOperationName") && msg.Properties["HttpOperationName"].ToString() == "HelpPageInvoke")
                {

                    return base.CheckAccessCore(operationContext);
                }

                var httpRequestHeaders = ((HttpRequestMessageProperty) msg.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]).Headers;

                // Is Authorization-header contained in http-headers?
                if (!httpRequestHeaders.AllKeys.Contains(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString()))
                {
                    //code returns here
                    return false;
                }

                    return false;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

As shown "Authorization" header is not included in req header array

[image]

In Firebug Under Request Headers for ajax reqeuest:

> Request Headersview source 
>   Accept    */*  Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5  Cache-Control   max-age=0
>   Connection    keep-alive  Host    test.proxyU.com  If-Modified-Since  Wed, 21
>   Mar 2012 19:46:56 GMT  If-None-Match  "e0818-17278-4bbc60dc86c00"
>   User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0

Update: Considering Answer below I have tried 3 Methods as below none of them adds the header. All call wcf correctly but `Authorization' header is just not in the request. And if I watch the http request the header looks very much like the screen shot I posted above

**Method 1**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:64121/Test.svc/json/GetNumber?X='+ var1 + '&callback=?'",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BasicAuthTest");},
        success: function(trackingData) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

**Method 2**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:64121/Test.svc/json/GetNumber?X='+ var1 + '&callback=?'",
        headers: {"Authorization": "BasicAuthTest"},
        success: function(trackingData) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

**Method 3**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:64121/Test.svc/json/GetNumber?X='+ var1 + '&callback=?'",
        beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
            $.extend(settings, { headers : { "Authorization" : "BasicAuthTest" } });
        },
        success: function(trackingData) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use developer tools in your browser (typically F12) and check if header added to request.

Comment: I updated the question with headers

Comment: @jaminator what version of jquery?

Comment: @drch 1.7.2, I just noticed in chrome debugger that when i use Method 3 instead of adding a whole new header I see: `Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, origin`

Comment: when I call this wcf from asp.net website using c# i see a complete new header entry `Authorization` being entered and it works fine. But from javascript/jquery it appears to be adding the header inside `Access-Control-Request-Headers`

Comment: is the page you're running the js from on the same origin (host, protocol, and port) as the service?  IE, http://localhost:64121/mypage.html .  If not, you are probably running into cross origin issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was a cross domain issue, I used [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-How-to-do-API-Key-Verification-with-a-WCF-WebHttp-REST-service/) visual studio project template and it made things fairly easy. There is a working example in there too for http get from the service

Comment: Can you explain what you did to fix this on localhost? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: just use the project template linked above, it has working example in it

Answer (score 1):

From documentation on [setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29)

> You must call setRequestHeader() after open(), but before send().

Looking at the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js#L4), open() is called on send() so you can't set the headers via the xhr object in beforeSend()

The jQuery documentation on $.ajax regarding headers says:

> This setting is set before the beforeSend function is called; therefore, any values in the headers setting can be overwritten from within the beforeSend function.

So you can update the headers in beforeSend(xhr, settings) via the settings object and jQuery will pick them up.

```
$.ajax({
    url:http://localhost:64121/Test.svc/json/GetNumber?X='+ var1 + '&callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
        $.extend(settings, { headers : { "Authorization", "BasicAuthTest" } }
    },
    success: function(trackingData) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a headers parameter into your $.ajax() call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    headers : { "Authorization", "BasicAuthTest" }
};
```

Comment: Updated question considering your answer